# I get the error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102d3c320)" how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I'm trying to make a simple video viewfinder by following AVFoundation documentation. The app terminates every time it is launched.  How do I resolve this particular error?

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102d3c320)
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toggleCameraButton: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var wideCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    var telephotoCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: .video, position: .back)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
        guard
            let wideCameraDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: wideCamera!)
            else { return }

        guard
            let telephotoCameraDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: wideCamera!)
            else { return }
        captureSession?.addInput(wideCameraDeviceInput)
        captureSession?.addInput(telephotoCameraDeviceInput)
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

        guard 
            (captureSession?.canAddOutput(videoOutput))! //Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102d3c320)
            else { return } 
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = .high
        captureSession?.addOutput(videoOutput)
        captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
        self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
        captureSession?.startRunning()
    }

    @IBAction func SwitchCameras(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func switchToTelephoto() {
    }

    func switchToWideAngle() {
    }

}

class PreviewView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }

    ///Convenience wrapper to get layer as its statically known type.
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }

}
```

console only displays

```
(lldb)
```

Comment: When the error happens, what if you click the Continue button or type `continue` at the lldb command line? Do we then launch and run?

Answer (score 0):

I would dive deep into why you use `!` on this line:

```
guard (captureSession?.canAddOutput(videoOutput))! else { return }
```

The reason a developer uses `guard` is to check for optional-bindings, but you are force unwrapping the optional anyway.

This is what it should look like (taken from a project of mine, thus, tested and working)

```
guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else { return }
```